# How do I set an upper bound to an INT value within a select statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm looking to make part of my query more performant by cutting down on the number of case statements I use. I have a select statement as below currently:

```
SELECT 
ID, 
CASE WHEN sum(Value1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as [Value1], 
CASE WHEN sum(Value2) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as [Value2], 
CASE WHEN sum(Value3) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as [Value3], 
CASE WHEN sum(Value4) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as [Value4],
....
FROM table
```

Essentially I want the query to simply produce a boolean, either a 0 or a 1, but the case statements have tripled the runtime for my query which is less ideal. Is there a way I can force a boolean output or set a maximum value for my select and trim away the cases?

Comment: Just a thought  ...  sign( sum(Value1) )

Comment: Think this is it!

Answer (score 1):

As John Cappelletti has provided, the expected output of limiting an INT value into a Boolean 0/1 output is achieved via the SIGN function. This reduces the runtime for the query significantly compared to the case statement.

Comment: But it does not return the same thing as the CASE statement, now does it?
According to the docs: `Returns the positive (+1), zero (0), or negative (-1) sign of the specified expression.`